# Do I need TensorFlow for Keras prediction

Tags: tensorflow, deployment, keras

I have trained a network model with TensorFlow backend Keras and save the trained network to a .h5 file. Right now I need to deploy this network on another new PC for prediction, can I only install Keras on that PC without TensorFlow and load this network for prediction ?

Comment: No, you need tensorflow.

Comment: NO, you just need Keras to load your .h5 file and run the prediction.

Comment: In principle, if your model uses only standard Keras stuff (that is, you do not directly use TensorFlow calls in a custom layer, for example), it should be possible to load and run the model with a different [backend](https://keras.io/backend/). Currently TensorFlow, Theano and CNTK are the only supported backends, but there is also a [NumPy backend on the works](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11068).